# Using activations at a specific layer as an input for an LLM such as OPT-350m

Tags: deep-learning, transformer, llm

I'm working with the OPT-350m model and aiming to utilize embeddings from different layers as inputs for generating data. I've encountered issues when trying to feed these embeddings back into the model using the provided methods.

```
# Import necessary libraries (e.g., PyTorch, Hugging Face Transformers)
import torch
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, OPTForCausalLM

model_name = "facebook/opt-350m"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
model = OPTForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_name)

# Encode the input text
inputs = tokenizer("hello", return_tensors="pt")

# Get model output including hidden states
outputs = model(**inputs, output_hidden_states=True)

# Extract embeddings from a specific layer (e.g., the second layer)
embeddings = outputs.hidden_states[1] 

output = model(inputs_embeds=embeddings)
```

However, the code above resulted in a shape error:

```
RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (2x1024 and 512x1024)
```

Additionally, I attempted to use **'get_input_embeddings()'** to extract embeddings, but it only provided embeddings from the initial stage, lacking the layer diversity I intended to explore.

```
# Insert a dummy input sentence
input_sentence = "London is the capital of"

# Tokenize the input sentence and get embeddings of the first layer
inputs = tokenizer(input_sentence, return_tensors="pt", padding=True, truncation=True)
with torch.no_grad():
    embeddings = model.get_input_embeddings()(inputs.input_ids)

# Use the embeddings as input to the same model
with torch.no_grad():
    output = model.generate(inputs_embeds=embeddings, max_length=10)
```

Is there a reliable method to effectively utilize embeddings from different layers as input to the OPT-350m model without encountering shape errors or limitations in layer selection?

Answer (score 0):

After conducting research, I devised a solution involving a wrapper class that overrides the **'forward()'** function. This approach enables the modification of specific layers.

```
def input_modification(hidden_states):
    modified_states = hidden_states
    return modified_states


class CustomLayerWrapper(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, layer):
        super().__init__()
        self.layer = layer

    def forward(self, hidden_states, attention_mask=None, layer_head_mask=None,
                past_key_value=None, output_attentions=None, use_cache=None):
        # Apply modifications to hidden_states here
        modified_hidden_states = input_modification(hidden_states)

        # Pass modified_hidden_states to the original layer
        return self.layer(modified_hidden_states, attention_mask, layer_head_mask,
                          past_key_value, output_attentions, use_cache)
```

To use this approach, you'd create an instance of the layer you intend to modify, wrap it inside the custom wrapper, and then replace the original layer with the wrapped layer.

```
# Create an instance of the layer you want to modify
custom_layer = model.base_model.decoder.layers[1]
# Wrap the layer inside the custom wrapper
wrapped_layer = CustomLayerWrapper(custom_layer)
# Replace the layer with the wrapped layer
model.base_model.decoder.layers[1] = wrapped_layer
```

By calling the 'model' with suitable input (even a dummy input), modifications to the layers can be achieved by altering the **'input_modification()'** function within the CustomLayerWrapper class.

This implementation allows flexibility in modifying specific layers while maintaining the overall architecture of the model.

However, ensure to replace the placeholder code within **'input_modification()'** with the actual modifications you aim to perform on the hidden_states. Also, handle errors per your application's needs, ensuring graceful error handling or default value assignment in case of exceptions.